# ExecutorService asynchronous never end the main method

Tags: java, java-8, task, executorservice, callable

I've to do a massive upload to a certain server - my program do each upload in about 1 second - but i will upload around 10 thousand documents each time.
To do this, i thought in use parallelism to send the documents in a good time. (My server already accept a lot of requests simultaneously).

So, i created a Task (implementing a Callable) that upload my document.
And put it in a ExecutorService.

ExecutorUpload.java

```
public void execute(){
   ExecutorService executor = Executors.newWorkStealingPool();

   //this code create the InputStream objects from 
   //real Files from disk using java.io.InputStream and java.io.File
   List<CallbackCreateDocumentTask> tasks = createTasks(...);

   //this list holds the Future objects to try to terminate the executorService
   List<Future<DocumentDTO>> futures = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

   //iterate the list and call the Tasks
   tasks.stream().forEach((task) -> futures.add(executor.submit(task)));

   executor.shutdown();

   //here i was trying to stop the executor,
   //but this makes me lose de asynchronous upload because
   //the application stops to wait this unique executoService to terminate,
   //and i've more than one executorService doing upload
   //executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

}

App.java

```
public static void main (String[] args){
    new ExecutorUpload().execute();
}
```

This code is allright. All my documents were uploaded by the Tasks, in all instances of ExecutorService that i created.
But, my application never ends. It's like it stay waiting for more unfinished executorServices;

Does anybody knows why my application never ends ?
I suspect a few things :

1. Java 8 never close the main method
2. My executorService's run in a never-ending thread, or something like
   that
3. My InputStream's doesnt are been closed, making the main method
   wait for it
4. Something with the File, not with the InputStream, related with the Files not been closed too...

Comment: Does your application finish transferring all the requested files?  The parallelization may not be gaining you as much as you think, so perhaps "never ends" is *really* "takes an hour to finish", or similar.

Comment: Do present a *complete* representative example -- that is, an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I think that this is happening, but because somehow i may be let the InputStream's opened. I've made i simplification to the question... my Task calls a Function (java8) when it ends, with the results... then i write a log with sl4fj with the name. I'll investigate it..

Comment: For debugging purposes, you should maybe start with one big file (big enough to keep your network busy a few seconds) then retry with 2 files parallel... remember that you network performance is probably more of a bottleneck than all the other tasks, so even when all uploads start within a few seconds, only few can complete within seconds.

Comment: I'll try this. Thanks for your response